# set length of `geom_hline` in `geom_bar` plot

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, stack

I have an `geom_bar` plot and I would like to set the length of the  `geom_hline`.

I have this data,

```
set.seed(666)
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date(), len= 156, by="4 day")[sample(156, 26)],
  IndoorOutdoor = rep(c(-1,1), 13), #Change so there are only 26 rows
  Xmin = sample(90, 26, replace = T),
  Ymin = sample(90, 26, replace = T),
  Zmin = sample(90, 26, replace = T)
)

df$XYZmin <- rowSums(df[,c("Xmin", "Ymin", "Zmin")])*df$IndoorOutdoor
df[,7:9] <- df[,3:5]*df[,2] #Adding the sign to each X/Y/Z
names(df)[7:9] <- paste0(names(df)[3:5],"p") #to differentiate from your X/Y/Z
require(ggplot2)

df.m <- melt(df[,c(1:2,6:9)], measure.vars=c("Xminp", "Yminp", "Zminp"))
df.m$pos <- c(as.Date("2013-04-15"), rep(Sys.Date(), (length(df.m$XYZmin)-1)))
df.m$foo <- 0
```

and then I try plotting it like this

```
plot.alt <- ggplot(df.m, aes(date, value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=0.5) + 
  geom_hline(aes(pos, foo), size = 0.8, colour = "green")
plot.alt
```

this gives the error message,

```
Warning message:
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0
```

and the plot,

[image: ddd]
if I try plotting it with `pos` as `as.numeric`,

```
df.m$pos <- as.numeric(df.m$pos)
```

I get this error,

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

How can I set the length of the green line?

Comment: If you want finer control over length use `geom_segment`. And warnings are not errors. Don't confuse the two!

Comment: Thanks, good point, it's an warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace `geom_hline()` with `geom_segment()` and set your starting and ending positions for `x` values.

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(date, value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width=0.5) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=min(pos),xend=max(pos),y=0,yend=0),colour="green")
```