# generalizing net/gross in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm doing a particular operation quite a bit, and I need help generalizing it.

I have a lot of data that "looks" kind of like this:

```
> hflights::hflights %>% tbl_df %>% mutate(month=Month, carrier=UniqueCarrier) %>% 
  group_by(month, carrier) %>% summarize(delay=sum(ArrDelay, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  dcast(month ~ carrier)

   month    AA   AS   B6    CO   DL    EV   F9    FL    MQ    OO   UA    US    WN    XE  YV
1      1    18  296  229 27031 1026  1337  851   216  2322  3957 -219 -1068 31701 24248  NA
2      2   461  249  802 15769 1657   730  707  1079  4283 11486  323  -663 36729 27861 -44
3      3   317  476 1037 49061  905  2529  673  1111  2524 12955 1665  -606 28758 50702 -38
4      4  1147  465  518 52086 1856  4483  515   927  5085 17439 1803  -711 47084 69590 260
5      5  1272   56  654 63413 1381  3563 1334  1213  7899 22190 1798  1627 73771 66972  18
6      6  -262  172  504 60042 3736  2618  744   983  4519 21652 6260  2140 40191 66456  49
7      7  -460  112 1241 41300 2868  1628  321   506  1529 23432 2780   497 21200 98484  34
8      8 -1417   59 1659 36106 -949   808   42 -1366   310 11038 3546   -84  6991 33554  34
9      9  -841 -364 -202 24857 1022  -424  151  -747 -1373  4502 1743   248 15592 31846  NA
10    10   215 -112  -45 26437 1082 -1005  277  -537   522    13 1833 -1878 14725 27539  NA
11    11    97   -5  -72 20339 -101   207  180   449  2286  2628  230 -1093  8424 24199  NA
12    12  2287 -242  310  6644 1281 -1082  585    79  2311  5900 -491  -951 12735 65269  NA
```

There are positive and negative values with some groups; in this case, month & carrier. I can plot it like this:

```
> hflights::hflights %>% tbl_df %>% mutate(month=Month, carrier=UniqueCarrier) %>% 
  group_by(month, carrier) %>% summarize(delay=mean(ArrDelay, na.rm=T)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=month, y=delay, fill=carrier)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Which gives me an eye-bleedy chart like this:

[image]

It also gives me the message:

```
Warning message:
Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0
```

This message is kind of what I'm after. I want to separate positive from negative so that I can see the "gross" amount, and also generate the sum per group and show the "net" amount.

For this dataset, I can do that like so:

```
> df <- hflights::hflights %>% tbl_df %>% 
  mutate(month=Month, carrier=UniqueCarrier) %>% 
  group_by(month, carrier) %>% summarize(delay=mean(ArrDelay, na.rm=T))
> ggplot(NULL, aes(x=month, y=delay, fill=carrier)) + 
  geom_bar(data=df %>% filter(delay > 0), stat='identity') + 
  geom_bar(data=df %>% filter(delay < 0), stat='identity') + 
  geom_bar(data=df %>% group_by(month) %>% summarize(delay=sum(delay, na.rm=T)), fill='black', width=0.25, alpha=0.5, stat='identity')
```

Which gives me this chestnut:

[image]

This is much nicer because in September, it doesn't do netting so I get a better sense of the magnitude of the positives and the negatives.

However, the above only works for this dataset. What happens when I have different groups? How do I generalize this?

Comment: How about [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481634/ggplot2-warning-stacking-not-well-defined-when-ymin-0)? Does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `position = "identity"` to `geom_bar` should get rid of the warning you are getting in your first plot.

The [reason](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ggplot2/FclZZmaVtGE/VEylnG7hm28J) for this warning is related to interpreting that bars have negative height instead of just negative values.